# How to account for duplicates when comparing collection of arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, collections

Good evening,

My program is comparing 2D Comparable collection of arrays and it has to result in an array of all the common elements, including duplicate values. For example when comparing the collection of { {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 1, 5} } the result must be {1, 1, 1}. The problem is in order to avoid a situation where the code duplicates a  value that shouldn't be I had to put in an if statement if the list contains the value don't add it. For example { {4, 7, 9}, {4, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 4} } would result in {4, 4} but the correct common array would be {4}. I'm stumped on how to achieve the goal of accounting for duplicate values without causing erroneous duplicates into the common array. Thank you for your time and help.

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CommonElements {

```
private int comparisons = 0;


public Comparable<?>[] findCommonElements(Comparable<?>[][] collections) {

    Comparable<?>[] queryArray = (Comparable<?>[])collections[0]; //first comparison array
    Arrays.sort(queryArray); //sort the array
    ArrayList<Comparable<?>> commonList = new ArrayList<Comparable<?>>(); //initialize dynamic array
    Comparable<?>[] commonArray = new Comparable[0]; //Initiating common array
    for(int i= 1; i < collections.length; i++) { //Compare all arrays in collection to queryArray
        Comparable<?>[] nextArray = (Comparable<?>[])collections[i]; //initiate a2 as the next array in collections
        Arrays.sort(nextArray); //sort the array
        for(int j = 0; j < queryArray.length; j++) { //Compare each index in queryArray to elements from other arrays
            for(int k = 0; k < nextArray.length; k++) { //traverse nextArray comparing to index in queryArray
                if(queryArray[j] == nextArray[k]) {
                    if(commonList.contains(nextArray[k])) { //avoid adding the value multiple times when compared to more than 1 array
                        ++comparisons; //add to comparison count
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                    commonList.add(queryArray[j]); //set new element to commonList
                    ++comparisons; //add to comparison count
                    break;
                    }
                }
                else {
                ++comparisons; //add to comparisons each time it compares an index
                }
            }
        }
        queryArray = commonList.toArray(new Comparable[commonList.size()]); //make the next queryArray equal to the current commonList
    }
    if(comparisons == 0) {
        commonArray = queryArray;
        return commonArray; //In case collections has single array
    }
    else {
        commonArray = commonList.toArray(new Comparable[commonList.size()]);
        return commonArray; //return the common array when loops finish
    }
}

public int getComparisons() {
    return comparisons;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not maintain a counter map for each array, and then iterate on the entries on any of the maps and take the minimum count across all map counters as the count of duplicates in arrays?

Answer (score 0):

We can maintain a counter array that maintains the count of elements in each array. We can then maintain the first counter as a basis and for each key in the counter map, find the minimum number of occurrences of that key across all arrays to find the least number of times that key appears across all arrays. Once we know the `count`, we can add that key to our result set `count` number of times.

```
    public Comparable<?>[] findCommonElements(Comparable<?>[][] collections) {
        Map<Comparable<?>, Integer>[] counterArray = new Map[collections.length];
        List<Comparable<?>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=0; i<collections.length; i++) {
            counterArray[i] = new HashMap<>();
            for (int j=0; j<collections[i].length; j++) {
                Comparable<?> comparable = collections[i][j];

                int newVal = counterArray[i].getOrDefault(comparable, 0);
                counterArray[i].put(comparable, newVal+1);
            }
        }

        if (collections.length == 1)
            return collections[0];

        for (Map.Entry<Comparable<?>, Integer> entry : counterArray[0].entrySet()) {
            Comparable<?> comparable = entry.getKey();
            int minCount = entry.getValue();

            for (int j=1; j<counterArray.length; j++) {
                minCount = Math.min(
                        minCount,
                        counterArray[j].getOrDefault(comparable, 0)
                );
            }

            for (int count = 1; count <= minCount; count++)
                result.add(comparable);
        }

        return result.toArray(Comparable[]::new);
    }

    public int getComparisons() {
        return comparisons;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately my professor restricted us from using Hex tables as this was not something we covered in the class prior to the assignment. I appreciate the advice though as I did notice many people offer similar solutions to problems like mine it seems like a handy solution.

Comment: I have no idea why I said Hex tables, I meant Hash Maps.